# How can i initiate hooks in a jQuery loaded page when creating a wordpress plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-plugins

Iam writing a wordpress widget with the following pages
1) I have master page (master.php)
   - is the main plugin page
   - Loads a second page (slave.php) with jQuery
2) The slave page
   - has php, jquery, css etc.
   - is an external page

Below is part of master.php

---

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'register_masterscript');
function register_masterscript() {
    wp_register_script( 'master_jquery', plugins_url('/js/master-script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '2.5.1' );
        wp_register_script( 'master_jquery2', plugins_url('/js/master.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '2.5.1' );
    wp_register_style( 'master_style', plugins_url('/css/master_style.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
}

// using the registered jquery and style above
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_masterstyle');

function enqueue_masterstyle(){
   wp_enqueue_script('master_jquery');
   wp_enqueue_script('master_jquery2');
   wp_enqueue_style( 'master_style' );
}
?>
```

master.php loads slave.ph successfully but my problem is non of the jquery actions or links work.
As slave.php is external I have tried

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
```

then

```
<?php 
add_action('init', 'register_slavescript');
function register_slavescript() {
    wp_register_script( 'slave_jquery', plugins_url('/js/jQuery1.7.1.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '2.5.1' );
        wp_register_script( 'slave_jquery2', plugins_url('/js/highlight.pack.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '2.5.1' );
        wp_register_script( 'slave_jquery3', plugins_url('/js/combined.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '2.5.1' );
    wp_register_style( 'slave_style', plugins_url('/css/slave_style.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
         wp_register_script( 'slave_jquery4', plugins_url('/js/jquery.mousewheel.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '2.5.1' );
         wp_register_script( 'slave_jquery5', plugins_url('/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '2.5.1' ); 
}       
// use the registered jquery and style above
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_slavestyle');

function enqueue_slavestyle(){
   wp_enqueue_script('slave_jquery');
   wp_enqueue_script('slave_jquery2');
   wp_enqueue_script('slave_jquery3');
   wp_enqueue_style( 'slave_style' );
   wp_enqueue_script('slave_jquery4');
   wp_enqueue_script('slave_jquery5');
}
?>
```

It looks like for slave.php enqueue -ing is not working, how can i do this the right way ?

Comment: Are the files not loaded? What is displayed? What are you trying to achieve by doing this master-slave dance? Why do you need to load WordPress twice?

Comment: Maybe am tired am sorry but I couldn't find the edit link under my questions as the instructions say. Since the master.php is loading well, and its links and jquery functions are ok, I decided to test it alone, by define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>    
<?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
<?php
endforeach; I can see expected results, but now the jquery scripts are no longer loading,

Comment: With master slave I am avoiding an iframe, by using jquery, jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
  $(function() {
 cache: false,
 127.0.0.1/livezone/wp-content/plugins/livebak3/slave.php
    $('#d1').html('<h4>Loading...</h4>').load(url);
    return false;
  });
 });

Comment: Why aren't you displaying it as a normal widget instead? Inline?

Comment: Thank you, I have finally resolved my problem, by redesigning the project, I made sure all the jquery and css scripts were on the first page ( master). its working fine now. But does this mean you can not use the wp_equeue_script on an external/custom page?

Answer (score 0):

While you are able to register scripts and styles without any issues in the way you're doing it, WordPress will not inject them onto the page automatically.

The chain of functions that actually do this is attached to several actions which are not triggered in your case.

Header scripts are output during [`wp_head`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L208), [`login_head`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L222) or [`admin_print_scripts`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L244); a similar thing happens with footer scripts.

The `wp_head` hook, for example, is triggered by themes calling `wp_head()` where appropriate. Did you slave call this? I don't think it id.

So overall, you'd have to call [`wp_print_head_scripts`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L796) and [`wp_print_footer_scripts`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L828) manually in order to output your queued scripts and styles on a custom bootstrapped page.

Speaking of custom bootstrapping: more often than not, custom bootstrapping is avoidable using [Widgets](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) and [AJAX](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). So if you find yourself loading WordPress manually on a page, you're very probably doing it wrong, especially if it involves iframes.

Comment: Well, thank you, Since i have redesigned the widget, I will just use this method, and it means there is no need for calling wp_head ? but may you please give me an example of how I can  append my css, after wordpress has called its own, so that mine will dominate. thanx

Comment: Like I said, call wp_print_head_scripts and wp_print_footer_scripts manually in your slave. For you scripts to dominate use wp_deregister_script/style if WordPress adds any that you don't need. Don't call wp_head, since there are other things it will inject besides the scripts and stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Following @soulseekah's answer, don't forget to call both `wp_head()` just before the `</head>` closing tag, and `wp_footer()` just before the `</body>` closing tag. These functions are generally required to render WordPress scripts and CSS tags by plugins or in the theme's specific insertions -- normally enqueued using `wp_enqueue_scripts()` or `wp_enqueue_styles()` in `functions.php` file.

Your theme won't pass the [unit tests](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test) if you don't have these functions in your template.

A good way of detecting this kind of issue is installing the [Theme Checker](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/) plugin. This will help you track your theme's functionality according to the [latest WordPress standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Review).